# LEFT JOIN on BETWEEN not using indexes

Tags: mysql, index, performance, join, query-performance

I am trying to join two tables on the criteria that the value one column of `table1` is between the values of two columns of `table2`.

#### Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE `values`(
  `id` INT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50),
  `num_addr` BIGINT UNSIGNED
);
```

#### Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE `ranges`(
  `id` INT,
  `range_name` VARCHAR(50),
  `range_start` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `range_end` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  INDEX `idx_start` (`range_start` ASC),
  INDEX `idx_end` (`range_end` ASC),
  INDEX `idx_range` (`range_start` ASC, `range_end` ASC)
);
```

The query:

```
SELECT
  `v`.`name`,
  `v`.`num_addr`,
  `r`.`range_name`
FROM
  `values` `v`
  LEFT JOIN `ranges` `r` ON `v`.`num_addr` BETWEEN `range_start` AND `range_end`
```

An `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` for the query shows that no index is used, with the information 'Range checked for each record (index map: 0x7)'. This is a performance issue as the ranges table has over 500,000 rows and the query is time sensitive.

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, r, ALL, idx_start,idx_end,idx_range, , , , 1, 100.00, Range checked for each record (index map: 0x7)
```

A `FORCE INDEX ON JOIN` actually makes things worse as the optimizer only sees the suggested index, but does not use it.

Is there a way to use an index on such joins?

Additional notes:

1. Changing the `BETWEEN` to `value >= range_start AND value <= range_end` does not change the execution plan.
2. Removing `idx_start` and `idx_end` indexes does not improve the situation.
3. Adding an index to `num_addr` does not affect the join execution.
4. The intervals `(range_start, range_end)` can overlap.
5. There are `num_addr` that are not in a range.
6. A good analogy is phone numbers: In the `ranges` table there would be a record: `('UK', 44000000000000, 44999999999999)` and another `('UK Vodafone', 44700000000000, 44799999999999)`.

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping ranges is an especially difficult problem to optimize.  However, here is a technique that provides significant performance, but it requires major change to the schema.

Add another table; let's call it `Prefixes`.  It contains two columns:

```
prefix DECIMAL(4,0) NOT NULL,
range_id INT,   -- for JOINing to `ranges`
PRIMARY KEY(prefix)
```

Then, to look for the number `4432109...`, first look up `4432` in `Prefixes.  This will lead to one or more`range.id` values for checking in your existing table.

Note that, for your example, there will 100 entries in `Prefixes` for 'UK' and 10 entries for 'UK Vodafone'.  This implies extra code to maintain `Prefixes`.

A variant on this is to move the rest of the `ranges` columns into my new table, and get rid of the table `ranges`.  (Whether to do this depends on the number and nature of the columns, the hassle in the code, the size of the 'prefix', the size of the table(s), etc, etc.)

Comment: Using the prefixes only will eliminate the overlapping, so it should improve performance. I will test this out soon, though I am unsure of how to join the `values` table with the `prefixes` table. If I use `LIKE`, I would have to contact `%` to all the `prefixes` which will hinder performance. Any suggestions? The prefixes can be of any length.

Comment: The optimal length for the Prefix table depends on the distribution of values, the sizes of the allocation ranges, etc.  It is a trade-off between one vendor being split into too many rows versus one prefix having too many vendors in it.

Comment: Please elaborate on `LIKE` -- I don't see where it could fit.

Comment: I am referring to the `LEFT JOIN` which is currently using a `BETWEEN`. From your answer I understood that it should now be something link `LEFT JOIN ranges r ON v.num_addr LIKE CONCAT(prefix, '%')`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `LEFT` means to keep the 'left' table even if there is no match on the 'right' table.  Perhaps you do _not_ mean that?

Comment: No, `LEFT` is what I mean. In the case that a value doesn't fall within a prefix / range, then it is an out-of-range value. This is expected to happen.